# Set contentInset and contentOffset in React Native's ScrollView

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to make my content start 100 px from the top in React Native. I have tried with

```
const OFFSET = 100
const ScrollViewTest = (props) => (
  <ScrollView
    contentInset={{ top: OFFSET }}
    contentOffset={{ y: OFFSET }}
  >
    <Text>Test</Text>
  </ScrollView>
)
```

But when I render the screen, it starts from 0 px, but if I scroll a little, it will scroll to 100px from the top and stay there.

So it seems React Native doen't trigger the `contentOffset` and `contentInset` properties on initialization.

How can I fix this? I have also tried setting `automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}` with no changes.

Also, it seems these properties are for iOS only. Are there any similar properties for Android?

Answer (score 12):

You should use the `contentContainerStyle`<sup>[1](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentcontainerstyle)</sup> property with a `marginTop` on your ScrollView.

By using this property it will apply the container wrapping your children (which I believe is what you want in this case) and with the additional benefit of working on both iOS and Android.

I.e.

```
const OFFSET = 100
const ScrollViewTest = (props) => (
  <ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{ marginTop: OFFSET }}
  >
    <Text>Test</Text>
  </ScrollView>
)
```

Comment: This solution works most of the times, but here are some cases where it is not a good idea: 
1) Having a transparent Header where the content should scroll underneath. 
2) When working with RefreshControl. 

1) Can be solved with replacing `contentContainerStyle` with `style={{paddingTop: headerHeight}}`
2) Needs to be solved with Inset & Offset like @Jamgreen suggested. However, I have the same problem as he has.

Comment: This does add the content offset but it also cuts off the end of the scroll view by the same margin

Answer (score 3):

```
    componentDidMount(){
        if(Platform.OS==='ios'){
          this.refs._scrollView.scrollToOffset({animated:false,offset:-OFFSET});
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <ScrollView
                ref="_scrollView"
                contentInset={{top: OFFSET}}
            ...>
               ...
           </ScrollView>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When I try to call scrollTo from componentDidMount method it does not scroll. I have to use workaround with setTimeout to make it work:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => this.refs._scrollView.scrollTo({ x: 100, y: 0 }) , 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in the comments to  Peter Theill's solution, the proposed solutions here do not work in 100% of the cases, e.g. for one of the following scenarios:

1. You have a transparent Header where you want the content to scroll underneath (e.g. a blurred header).

You could solve this with Peter Theill's solution and replacing `contentContainerStyle` with `style={{paddingTop: headerHeight}}`.

But this won't help you if you have also the following typical scenario:

2. You want to use RefreshControl. It will be displayed behind the header and there is no way to position it differently on iOS. Therefore, you need to use contentOffset & contentInset as Jamgreen proposed. However, I had kind of similar issues with initial rendering of offset. I solved it in my case with the prop `automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}`, so I would recommend to try this!

Here is the complete solution (for android & iOS) in my scenario:

```
<ScrollView
    style={{paddingTop: Platform.select({android: headerHeight, ios: 0})}}
    scrollIndicatorInsets={{ right: 1 }}
    ref={scrollViewRef}
    contentInset={{ top: headerHeight}}
    contentOffset={{ x: 0, y: Platform.select({android: 0, ios: -headerHeight})}}
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    refreshControl={<RefreshControl
        refreshing={refresh}
        onRefresh={() => {
            setRefresh(true);
            setTimeout(() => setRefresh(false), 10000);
        }}
        colors={[inputPlaceholderGray]}
        tintColor={inputPlaceholderGray}
        progressViewOffset={headerHeight}
    />}
>
    {CONTENT}
</ScrollView>
```

Hope it still helps people although the issue is already old.

Answer (score 0):

padding-like effect:

```
const OFFSET = 100
const ScrollViewTest = (props) => (
    <ScrollView>
        <View style={{ height: OFFSET }} />
        <Text>Test</Text>
    </ScrollView>
)
```

header-like effect:

```
const OFFSET = 100
const ScrollViewTest = (props) => (
    <View style={{ paddingTop: OFFSET }}>
        <ScrollView>
            <Text>Test</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    </View >
)
```

Comment: But if, instead of `<Text>..</Text>` have a `<FlatList>` with `RefreshControl`, the refresh button will be before the padding-like effect instead of just above the list, so I cannot accomplish the same :(

Comment: Interesting what overflow: “hidden” will do in this case